# Как создать список кнопок?

Tags: android, view, design

Здравствуйте. Часто вижу в приложениях списки элементов, с текстом и иконкой, по которым можно кликать (на скриншотах). Внешне похожи на menu или группы настроек, но используются​ не только в preference screen. Подскажите, кто знает, с помощью каких view создаётся подобное?

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/JSSkf.png]

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/NSIVP.png]

Comment: `NavigationView`?

Comment: @pavlofff по-моему он так раз таки хочет использовать подобное не в NavigationView.

Comment: Ну такой список можно сделать с помощью recyclerView.

Comment: @Morozov `NavigationView` не обязательно использовать для выезжающего меню, можно сделать и статичным на весь экран, это обычный виджет для отображения пунктов меню  и самый простой способ [получить такие пункты](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33607630/7566397), как на втором сриншоте (ну и на первом, понятно, тоже) - без всяких списков, адаптеров, кастомных вью айтема и прочих мраков :)

Comment: @pavlofff хм) полезный point) опробуем)